# Blue button instead of purple

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have material-ui with react and when adding a button and setting the color to primary it becomes purple. I was expecting it to be blue, based on this site:
https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/

Code:

```
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Primary
      </Button>
```

How to make this button blue?

Comment: are you using `@material-ui/core/styles';`

Comment: Please close this post if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color for buttons uses color themes of Material UI.
Look at the doc to override style :
https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overrides

There is many solutions but here you can use inline style like :

```
style={{background: 'blue'}}
```

Here is an example :
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4pfve

Answer (score 2):

They have a link to code sandbox there ( https://codesandbox.io/s/8kq6zk5kq9 ). It shows slightly other colors as on the page. So I guess they are just outdated on the site and the colors you have are the new ones.

If you really want the blue color you should use the 'withStyles' function of Material UI, as described on the page you posted.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  }
});

function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
        Primary
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

ContainedButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ContainedButtons);
```

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI documentation site uses a custom theme. This is mentioned in the docs, see https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/. The theme object is customizable.

If you are looking to have the same color combinations as the documentation, you need to use the theming. An example is provided here - https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables

For example, you could do something like below, to get the same primary color as the documentation site,

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#1976d2"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#dc004e"
    }
  }
});

export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Primary
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

For more color combinations you could also use the color tool here https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#color-tool, where you can select the primary/secondary color combination and click on "Set Docs Colors" button to see how it reflects on the documentation.